# Is there a way to use the Youtube API v3 to grab past subscriber counts?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

From everything I have researched I have not been able to find a way to grab past subscriber count on a certain date. If I can't do it through Youtube API is there any other site that would have this kind of data I could grab for a bunch of different channels?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with all of the updates to YouTube showing rounded subscriber counts. I would recommend checking out the YouTube Analytics & Reporting APIs at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics. Other than that, I would say not.